# javascript library for drawing file and folder structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm looking for a way to let my user create file and folder inside their own folder in my web application and **show them the file and folder Explorer structure inside their page and let them work with those files and folder.**

is there any library available for this ?

---

Added ->
My App is a server side app and I want file and folder manager page be something like dropbox or box cloud file manager pages.

Comment: For future reference, @M2hp, a question on SO asking people to recommend an off-site resource or library will get downvoted and closed pretty quickly [as they are considered off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You were lucky in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app a client side app or a server side app (php/java...)?

Maybe this helps: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/

Comment: Server Side APP, Spring MVC and JSP, thanks for your answer